# How to backup root-ca-only from UCP replica

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, docker-ucp, dtr

I am trying to backup UCP master root-ca-only from UCP replica server:

```
docker run --rm -i --name ucp -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker/ucp:1.1.0 backup --root-ca-only --id 4G26:AMCX:67XR:TIKD:CXYS:3PKD:5O66:SKZM:T22Q:OYYL:BV2H:QJ3D --url https://ucp-master-url > backup.tar
```

It is not working. Please suggest the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the interactive mode like this:

`docker run --rm -i --name ucp -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker/ucp backup --root-ca-only --passphrase "secret" > backup.tar -i`

I am getting `time="2016-06-17T00:51:17Z" level=fatal msg="flag provided but not defined: -url"` with `--url`. You can pass the fingerprint with `--id xxx` like you did, just don't use the `--url`.